# Keep VideoPlayerController playing audio when closing the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to develop an app that presents videos to the user. I am using `VideoPlayerController` for loading the videos, and `ChewieController` for the UI.

It works great, but when the user closes the app, the video stops. I would like the video to keep playing its audio even when closing the app/locking the device.

I couldn't find anything about it on the `VideoPlayerController` and in the `ChewieController` documentations.

Is this functionality possible in Flutter and Dart?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look how native variant is for 'services - broadcast and provider vs static context' maybe can help you.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately Flutter's `video_player` package doesn't support background video or audio playing. But you can use `flutter_playout` which wraps `ExoPlayer` on Android and `AVPlayer` framework on iOS with the ability to playback video in background or even lock screen. You can find out more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout). Below is an example code provided by library's GitHub repo which plays a video and it keeps playing in background

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout/multiaudio/HLSManifestLanguage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout/multiaudio/MultiAudioSupport.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout/player_observer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout/player_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout/video.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playout_example/hls/getManifestLanguages.dart';

class VideoPlayout extends StatefulWidget {
  final PlayerState desiredState;
  final bool showPlayerControls;

  const VideoPlayout({Key key, this.desiredState, this.showPlayerControls})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayoutState createState() => _VideoPlayoutState();
}

class _VideoPlayoutState extends State<VideoPlayout>
    with PlayerObserver, MultiAudioSupport {
  final String _url = null;
  List<HLSManifestLanguage> _hlsLanguages = List<HLSManifestLanguage>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, _getHLSManifestLanguages);
  }

  Future<void> _getHLSManifestLanguages() async {
    if (!Platform.isIOS && _url != null && _url.isNotEmpty) {
      _hlsLanguages = await getManifestLanguages(_url);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          /* player */
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            child: Video(
              autoPlay: true,
              showControls: widget.showPlayerControls,
              title: "MTA International",
              subtitle: "Reaching The Corners Of The Earth",
              preferredAudioLanguage: "eng",
              isLiveStream: true,
              position: 0,
              url: _url,
              onViewCreated: _onViewCreated,
              desiredState: widget.desiredState,
            ),
          ),
          /* multi language menu */
          _hlsLanguages.length < 2 && !Platform.isIOS
              ? Container()
              : Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: _hlsLanguages
                        .map((e) => MaterialButton(
                              child: Text(
                                e.name,
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .button
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setPreferredAudioLanguage(e.code);
                              },
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onViewCreated(int viewId) {
    listenForVideoPlayerEvents(viewId);
    enableMultiAudioSupport(viewId);
  }

  @override
  void onPlay() {
    // TODO: implement onPlay
    super.onPlay();
  }

  @override
  void onPause() {
    // TODO: implement onPause
    super.onPause();
  }

  @override
  void onComplete() {
    // TODO: implement onComplete
    super.onComplete();
  }

  @override
  void onTime(int position) {
    // TODO: implement onTime
    super.onTime(position);
  }

  @override
  void onSeek(int position, double offset) {
    // TODO: implement onSeek
    super.onSeek(position, offset);
  }

  @override
  void onDuration(int duration) {
    // TODO: implement onDuration
    super.onDuration(duration);
  }

  @override
  void onError(String error) {
    // TODO: implement onError
    super.onError(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the video_player package now has the allowBackgroundPlayback option, I created this simple example showing how to integrate video_player and audio service.

[example_video_player.dart](https://github.com/azamor-luccas/audio_service/blob/minor/audio_service/example/lib/example_video_player.dart)

```
// This example demonstrates a simple video_player integration.

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

// You might want to provide this using dependency injection rather than a
// global variable.
late AudioPlayerHandler _audioHandler;

Future<void> main() async {
  _audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => AudioPlayerHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Audio Service Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4',
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(allowBackgroundPlayback: true))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _audioHandler.setVideoFunctions(_controller.play, _controller.pause, _controller.seekTo, () {
          _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero);
          _controller.pause();
        });

        // So that our clients (the Flutter UI and the system notification) know
        // what state to display, here we set up our audio handler to broadcast all
        // playback state changes as they happen via playbackState...
        _audioHandler.initializeStreamController(_controller);
        _audioHandler.playbackState.addStream(_audioHandler.streamController.stream);

        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Close the stream
    _audioHandler.streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Service Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: _controller.value.isInitialized
                  ? AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ),
            // Play/pause/stop buttons.
            StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: _audioHandler.playbackState.map((state) => state.playing).distinct(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final playing = snapshot.data ?? false;
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    _button(Icons.fast_rewind, _audioHandler.rewind),
                    if (playing) _button(Icons.pause, _audioHandler.pause) else _button(Icons.play_arrow, _audioHandler.play),
                    _button(Icons.stop, _audioHandler.stop),
                    _button(Icons.fast_forward, _audioHandler.fastForward),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
            // Display the processing state.
            StreamBuilder<AudioProcessingState>(
              stream: _audioHandler.playbackState.map((state) => state.processingState).distinct(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final processingState = snapshot.data ?? AudioProcessingState.idle;
                return Text("Processing state: ${(processingState)}");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconButton _button(IconData iconData, VoidCallback onPressed) => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(iconData),
        iconSize: 64.0,
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );
}

class MediaState {
  final MediaItem? mediaItem;
  final Duration position;

  MediaState(this.mediaItem, this.position);
}

/// An [AudioHandler] for playing a single item.
class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with SeekHandler {
  late StreamController<PlaybackState> streamController;

  static final _item = MediaItem(
    id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3',
    album: "Science Friday",
    title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
    artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
    artUri: Uri.parse('https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
  );

  Function? _videoPlay;
  Function? _videoPause;
  Function? _videoSeek;
  Function? _videoStop;

  void setVideoFunctions(Function play, Function pause, Function seek, Function stop) {
    _videoPlay = play;
    _videoPause = pause;
    _videoSeek = seek;
    _videoStop = stop;
    mediaItem.add(_item);
  }

  /// Initialise our audio handler.
  AudioPlayerHandler();

  // In this simple example, we handle only 4 actions: play, pause, seek and
  // stop. Any button press from the Flutter UI, notification, lock screen or
  // headset will be routed through to these 4 methods so that you can handle
  // your audio playback logic in one place.

  @override
  Future<void> play() async => _videoPlay!();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() async => _videoPause!();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) async => _videoSeek!(position);

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async => _videoStop!();

  void initializeStreamController(VideoPlayerController? videoPlayerController) {
    bool _isPlaying() => videoPlayerController?.value.isPlaying ?? false;

    AudioProcessingState _processingState() {
      if (videoPlayerController == null) return AudioProcessingState.idle;
      if (videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized) return AudioProcessingState.ready;
      return AudioProcessingState.idle;
    }

    Duration _bufferedPosition() {
      DurationRange? currentBufferedRange = videoPlayerController?.value.buffered.firstWhere((durationRange) {
        Duration position = videoPlayerController.value.position;
        bool isCurrentBufferedRange = durationRange.start < position && durationRange.end > position;
        return isCurrentBufferedRange;
      });
      if (currentBufferedRange == null) return Duration.zero;
      return currentBufferedRange.end;
    }

    void _addVideoEvent() {
      streamController.add(PlaybackState(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.rewind,
          if (_isPlaying()) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.fastForward,
        ],
        systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.seek,
          MediaAction.seekForward,
          MediaAction.seekBackward,
        },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
        processingState: _processingState(),
        playing: _isPlaying(),
        updatePosition: videoPlayerController?.value.position ?? Duration.zero,
        bufferedPosition: _bufferedPosition(),
        speed: videoPlayerController?.value.playbackSpeed ?? 1.0,
      ));
    }

    void startStream() {
      videoPlayerController?.addListener(_addVideoEvent);
    }

    void stopStream() {
      videoPlayerController?.removeListener(_addVideoEvent);
      streamController.close();
    }

    streamController = StreamController<PlaybackState>(onListen: startStream, onPause: stopStream, onResume: startStream, onCancel: stopStream);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you know how can I remove the notification after stop or close the app? I'm using SwitchAudioHandler, but I can't remove the video notification.

Comment: the notification is controlled by the processingState. So, if you add a new playbackState event to the stream with processingState=AudioProcessingState.idle inside the dispose() method, the notification should close. But I'm 100% sure that this will work.

Comment: its a little bit broken. The AudioProcessingState.ready doesn't change to AudioProcessingState.idle after the stop button has been pressed

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) package. It's quite good uses `video_player` and `chewie` and also has support for [player notification](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player#setup-player-notification) and PiP.

And don't forget to enable the background audio capability on your xcode.
[xcode-audio-capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uukQn.png)

Answer (score 0):

here is an update to @Luccas Azamor's answer

i found a way hot to change  AudioProcessingState to idle and remove it from background player after the stop button has been pressed

```
AudioProcessingState _processingState() {
      if (videoPlayerController == null) return AudioProcessingState.idle;
      if (videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized) {
        if (videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
          return AudioProcessingState.ready;
        } else {
          return AudioProcessingState.idle;
        }
      }
      return AudioProcessingState.idle;
    }
```