Video playback stops after I turn screen off, in Flutter
I used https://pub.dev/packages/video_player for video playback in Flutter.
But it has a problem, when I turn off screen, video and audio playback stops, I want it to continue to playback so I hear the audio and maybe turn off screen again and continue watching.
I tried allowBackgroundPlayback, but no effect.

Maybe you can check for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63400036/5078902

But flutter_playout  is not updated for 3 years.
